How to set a value to LiveData.setValue() when network response is not successful?
Let's say I have a User view model to load the user's data. I would use Retrofit2 to load the users data. A simple example would be like this:
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            userMutableLiveData.setValue(response.body());
        } else {
            //since response.body() is null, how to set a suitable value to userMutableLiveData.setValue()
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
        //since there was a networking failure, how to set a suitable value to userMutableLiveData.setValue()
    }
});


 // Wrapper class to handle success and error states
    public class Resource<T> {
        public enum Status { SUCCESS, ERROR }
        
        public final T data;
        public final String message;
        public final Status status;
    
        public Resource(T data, String message, Status status) {
            this.data = data;
            this.message = message;
            this.status = status;
        }
    
        public static <T> Resource<T> success(T data) {
            return new Resource<>(data, null, Status.SUCCESS);
        }
    
        public static <T> Resource<T> error(String message) {
            return new Resource<>(null, message, Status.ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    // ViewModel class
    public class UserViewModel extends ViewModel {
        private MutableLiveData<Resource<User>> userMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    
        public LiveData<Resource<User>> getUserLiveData() {
            return userMutableLiveData;
        }
    
        public void fetchUserData() {
            ApiService apiService = RetrofitClient.getApiService();
            apiService.getUser().enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        userMutableLiveData.setValue(Resource.success(response.body()));
                    } else {
                        userMutableLiveData.setValue(Resource.error("Failed to load user data"));
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                    userMutableLiveData.setValue(Resource.error(t.getMessage()));
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    // Retrofit API interface
    public interface ApiService {
        @GET("user")
        Call<User> getUser();
    }
    
    // Retrofit Client
    public class RetrofitClient {
        private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    
        public static ApiService getApiService() {
            return retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
        }
    }


Your Answer is unclear, could you provide more information to complete your answer and provide better clarification to the question.
